# How do I close a file that retrieves the latest excel sheet after running it and not saving it

Tags: excel, vba

Hello this is probably a simple fix but I got my macro to run but I need to close and not save the file I called after I run the macro.

I already treid activeworkbook close and close.workbooks but im not sure what is the name of my workbook since it retrieves the latest one

```
Sub oversub()
    'Latest File Code
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date
    Dim LMD As Date

    MyPath = "C:\Users\TAmon1\Desktop\OverSubscription Dash"
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.csv", vbNormal)
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
        If LMD > LatestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            LatestDate = LMD
        End If
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

    Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
    'Variables for Vlookup

    Dim wbcsv As Workbook, wbplanning As Workbook
    Set wbplanning = Workbooks("Planning_tool.xlsm")
    Set wbcsv = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & LatestFile)
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Windows("Planning_tool.xlsm").Activate

    wbplanning.Sheets(1).Range("N2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(C[-13],'" & wbcsv.Name & "'!C1:C11,11,FALSE)"
    Range("N2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N539")

    wbplanning.Sheets(1).Range("o2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(C[-14],'" & wbcsv.Name & "'!C1:C11,5,FALSE)"
    Range("o2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("o2:o539")
    Columns("N:O").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    ''Need to close latest file and not save insert code here    
End Sub
```

When I tried all of the method I escribed i get a out of range error.

Comment: `Dim wb as Workbook`, then `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & LatestFile)`. Then `wb.Close SaveChanges:=False`.

Comment: That works Thank you!!!!